# Using mutate() returns error about can't modify because it's a grouping variable

Tags: r, dplyr

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `month` can't be modified because it's a grouping variable
```

I would like to plot with one of the axis's being month of the year, however I would like it to go from August to July. I would also like "week" to display 1-5 instead of 5-1.....but it is not letting me do so when I try the following code:

```
Admit_Weekly1 <- Admit_Weekly %>% 
+   filter(Retention_Status == 1) %>% 
+   mutate(week = factor(week,levels(week)[1,2,3,4,5])) %>% 
+   mutate(month = factor(month,levels(month)["August","September","October","November",
+                                             "December","January","February","March",
+                                             "April", "May","June","July"]))
```

Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `week` can't be modified because it's a grouping variable

Comment: Remove the grouping variables with `ungroup()` before you mutate.

Comment: How would I do this in this context? Like where exactly would that go? Also, I am unsure this will help since I need it grouped for my plot.

Comment: I think you're confused about what "grouped" means in this context. At some point you called `group_by()` and included `week`. This means that the variable `week` is sort of **flagged** as a "grouping variable" going forward. Variables with this flag cannot be modified unless you remove that flag by inserting `ungroup() %>%` on the line prior to your first mutate. This will have no impact on your plot.

Comment: If you type `Admit_Weekly` in the console, you will likely see a summary of that object that includes an explicit description of which variables are grouping variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and solved it using the ungroup():

```
df <- df %>%
ungroup(var) %>%
mutate(var = factor(var,levels = c(1,2,3),
                    labels = c("label1","label2","label3") ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I realized I was using **dplyr 0.8.5** instead of **dplyr 1.0.7**. Once I did the update of the package (o reinstall it) it worked without adding the `ungroup() %>%` line.